# Contour heat graph (ListContourPlot?)

Tags: plotting

I have solved 2D incompressible Navier Stokes and written out a .dat file that includes x,y,u,v,p values. I am trying to get a 2D color heat graph like this one for my data

[image]

Here is what I have done so far trying to use Contourplot:

```
Data = Import[
"C:\\Users...
UVP-steady-state.dat", "Table"];
x = Data[[3 ;; 16002, 1]];
y = Data[[3 ;; 16002, 2]];
u = Data[[3 ;; 16002, 3]];
v =  Data[[3 ;; 16002, 4]];
p =  Data[[3 ;; 16002, 5]];
grid = Transpose[{x, y}];
ListPlot[grid, PlotLabel -> "MeshPoints", AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
PlotRange -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
velocity = Transpose[{x, y, Sqrt[u*u + v*v]}];
pressure = Transpose[{x, y, p}];
ListContourPlot[velocity]
ListContourPlot[pressure]
```

My steady state solution is in this .dat file

http://www.wikiupload.com/VSPA5GS9BAXQ830

I am able to make my solution look like this with TecPlot. 
[image]

For some reason Mathematica with ListContourPlot plots two fairly large gaps in the middle of the graph.

Comment: Try `ColorFunction` and `ColorData`.

Comment: @l3win, out of curiosity, how did you solve the Navier-Stokes equations?

Comment: @ruebenko any chance in future for `NDSolve` to solve Navier-Stokes out of the box..?

Comment: I used what is called the Projection Method for incompressible Navier-Stokes. I did not solve it with Mathematica but with Fortran :)

Comment: @PlatoManiac, as much as I would like too, my contract with WRI does not allow me to discuss future development. I do, however, have a Navier-Stokes solver written in Mathematica. It would need (a lot of :-) polishing, however.

Comment: @l3win thanks. I thought perhaps you had a Mathematica version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is similar to your picture:

```
ListContourPlot[velocity, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
                PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, Contours -> 99, 
                ContourStyle -> {None}]
```

[image]

But this is on a finer grain

```
ListContourPlot[velocity, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
ListContourPlot[velocity, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
                PlotLegends -> Automatic, Contours -> 99, ContourStyle -> {None}]
```

[image]

Comment: Aaah Mathematica 9!!! Your `PlotLegends` is now fixed.... it was so messed up in Mathematica 8.0

Comment: what do you mean fixed? I am unable to use the command belisarius posted. It gives me an error for PlotLegends

Comment: Does ListContourPlot only take in PlotLegends for Mathematica 9?

Comment: Maybe I just have to edit how the contours are plotted and the range which they are plotted. Trying to get rid of the two big white gaps in the middle of the graph still

Comment: @l3win There is a scaling problem. Let me try to fix it

Comment: @l3win Try `ListContourPlot[velocity, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, Contours -> 99, 
 ContourStyle -> {None}]`

Comment: Hey that works, thx

Comment: Do you know why I can't use PlotLegends? Does PlotLegends not work with ListContourPlot in Mathematica 8?

Comment: Never mind, just got mathematica 9.0 and now it work.